# Where is the verb of subject Senators

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, syntax

> Senators demanding a full debate over government spying and civil liberties objected, and lawmakers simply ran out of time.

What is the verb of subject "senators"?

Comment: 'Objected'. The words in between tell us which senators did so.

Comment: The matrix (main) verb is "objected". The subordinate clause "demanding a full debate over government spying and civil liberties" has "senators" as subject and "demanding" as verb.

Comment: Incidentally, the subject of the sentence is not just senators, but "senators demanding a full debate over government spying and civil liberties".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main verb is "objected" (the past tense form of "to object")

The subject is "senators demanding a full debate over government spying and civil liberties", with the long participle phrase "demanding..." describing the senators who objected. The verb is intransitive and there is no direct or indirect object.

The sentence is hard to parse because it doesn't follow the principle of "end weight", in which later parts of a sentence or clause tend to be longer.

Answer (score -1):

> Demanding.

The verb is “demanding,” as in the senators are demanding.

Comment: No, at least not the way the OP presumably means the question. _demanding_ is a (non-finite) verb in the participial clause, and _senators_ is the subject of that; but the main (finite) verb of which _senators_ is the subject is _objected_.

Comment: Subjects must have a finite (i.e. conjugated) verb. The conjugation to go with "senators" is "demand", not "demanding" (a non-finite verb form). The meaning of the sentence is not that the senators are demanding, but that they are objecting.